# Interesting result: Why does orderby affect so much time in the Doctrine query?

Tags: symfony, time, doctrine, response

Symfony framework Doctrine: When we run the following query on a table with 10 million rows, the response time exceeds 1 minute. When we take the sql of the same query and run it in the database, the end returns within a few seconds.

We solved the problem with the limit and continued our work. But we could not understand why this was so. There is no problem with indexes, no cache. Anyone have any ideas?

Additional info: Everything works normally when orderby is removed.

response time : more than 1 minute.

```
'$result=$entityManager->getRepository(CourseSuccess::class)
->createQueryBuilder('cs')
->join('cs.course','c')
->join(User::class,'ku','With','ku.username=cs.user')
->where('cs.successDate is not null')
->orderBy('cs.successDate')
->getQuery()->getResult();`
```

response time: a few seconds

```
'SELECT * FROM course_success c2_ 
INNER JOIN courses c0_ ON c2_.course_id = c0_.id AND (c0_.deleted_at IS NULL) 
INNER JOIN user k1_ ON (k1_.username = c2_.user) 
WHERE c2_.success_date IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY c2_.success_date ASC;`
```

I expected both of them to respond in approximate time.

Comment: You're comparing different queries - the doctrine one doesn't join on deleted_at=NULL. What's the response time for the doctrine query written as plain SQL?

Comment: I got the same question from Symfony Profiler debug. What makes you think it's different? second in under a second.

Comment: Did you check the executed query inside the profiler in the SQL tab ? Maybe another library modify the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem gedmo.

```
$entityManager->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
```

I disabled it, response time is back to normal.